# PHPMailer: Using remote SMTP server, works under localhost, Connection refused (111) on remote server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I've got a bizarre problem here. I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send an email, through SMTP. I have a website hosted by GoDaddy and it's that SMTP account that I'm trying to use to send the mail.

1. It works if I execute my PHP file on my localhost server.
2. It does not work if I execute my PHP file on GoDaddy's server.

The error message I get is:

`SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)`

I checked `phpinfo` on both localhost and the remote server. Both have `smtp_port` listed as `25`. I'm using WAMP on my machine and the server is some form of Linux (which I know nothing about and have no idea how to administer).

Here is the code in question:

**INDEX.PHP**:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
include_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'username@site.com';
$mail->Password = 'super_secret_password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // tried ssl and tls, with same result

$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->AddAddress('receiver@hotmail.com', 'Receiver Name');
$mail->From = "username@site.com";
$mail->FromName = "Username";
$mail->Subject = 'Hi there';
$mail->Body = "This is a message";

if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message sent!\n";
}
else {
    echo "Message failed!\n";
    print_r($mail->ErrorInfo);
}

exit();
?>
```

Comment: PHP may be working on 25, the SMTP server you're trying to connect to may not be. Check with your hosting provider for instructions on the proper usage of their relay.

Comment: @Zarathuztra If that was the issue, then it should fail in both situations - as in each case I am utilizing the same SMTP server.

Comment: In that case, make sure 25 is open. Is IPtables running on your hosting box? Login and run sudo iptables -L to see what rules are in there and check if SMTP is allowed to passthrough.

Comment: @Zarathuztra As I highlighted in my question, I have no idea how to do anything you just suggested. For instance, what do you mean by "Login"? The only way I'm used to logging in is via FTP, which I'm guessing is not what you're referring to.

Comment: connection refused means that someting actively denied the connection. either the smtp server isn't running on port 25 and the tcp connect failed, or there's a firewall that blocks external port 25 with an icmp rejection

Comment: If you can't use a linux command line, I would strongly recommend learning at least a few basics, else this issue is never going to be resolved.

Comment: godaddy is possibly the worse host in existence, you did use to have to use there scripts to send email from php.

Comment: @Dagon Yes, they have their problems. However, in investigating VPS hosts, I have yet to find a suitable alternative that can match their prices and up-time guarantee. If you have any solid suggestions, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 6):

I think  you should perform two step 
1) check your port as suggested on godaddy support http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/319/what-do-i-do-if-i-have-trouble-connecting-to-my-email-account
2)use "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" as your host instead of "smtpout.secureserver.net"

GoDaddy does allow to send emails using Gmail as your SMTP, just need to get rid of the smtp.gmail.com and use their Host instead. This is my setup:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Username = "your-account@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
// ...
// send from, send to, body, etc...
```

Reference (see first two posts) http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/phpmailer-with-godaddy-smtp-email-server-script-working/

Answer (score 2):

If your hosting has own email server, the server will use the following ports 25,465,587. 
Settings for GoDaddy:

```
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = localhost; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
//$mail->Port = 587;
```

For other providers you have to create a mailbox with your domain:

```
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = localhost; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'example@yourdomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
//$mail->Port = 587;
```